# 2D intensity map with cursors in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, events, matplotlib

I am currently trying to create a simple GUI based on matplotlib(Python 2.7).
My aim is to plot a 2d intensity map and look at the x and y slices with a user controlled curser.

It already worked out the way I want it.(See the example below).
But it seems that there is one mayor limitation in the program given by the array size I can use.
If I exceed a few million entries in the array the process starts to lag. I think the reason for that is that I redraw all the figures during the movement of the curser.

Is there an option how can I only redraw the curser and the slices but not the intensity map? I didn't find anything on that.
Or is there another option, except for writing the curser with a real GUI like Tkinter?

In the example below the initial position of the Cursor is on 00. And will will follow the mouse movement if you press the right mouse button near the curser position and keep it pressed until you shifted the cursor to the desired position and release the button.

```
    # -*- noplot -*-
    #from __future__ import print_function
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    
    
    class Cursor(object):
        """
        creates a GUI object that plots given 2d data with imshow and creates a curser
        which can be moved by drag and drop. The horizontal and vertical line of the curser
        are giving the position of a sliced trough the 2d-data and are plotted separately.

        """
        def __init__(self,data,scale_x,scale_y):
            
            self.motion=False
            self.data=data
            self.scale_x=scale_x
            self.scale_y=scale_y
            self.create_fig()
            # text location in axes coords
            self.txt = self.ax1.text(0.7, 0.9, '', transform=self.ax1.transAxes)
            self.create_events()
            
    #        print self.range_x,self.range_y
    #        print 
    #        print 
            
        def create_events(self):
            """
            Handles user events
            """
            self.cid1=plt.connect('motion_notify_event', self.mouse_move)
            self.cid2=plt.connect('button_press_event', self.mouse_press)
            self.cid3=plt.connect('button_release_event', self.mouse_release)
            
        def create_fig(self):
            """
            Creates the GUI, initializes the cursers at minimum of the axes and plots the 2d-data
            """
            
            #Create figure and axes
            f=plt.figure(dpi=150)
            self.ax1=f.add_subplot(221)
            self.ax2=f.add_subplot(223,sharex=self.ax1)
            self.ax3=f.add_subplot(222,sharey=self.ax1)
            # plot in ax1
            self.ax1.imshow(self.data,interpolation='none',aspect='auto',extent=[np.min(self.scale_x),np.max(self.scale_x),np.min(self.scale_y),np.max(self.scale_y)])
            
            #Creates the limits
            self.ax1.axis([np.min(self.scale_x),np.max(self.scale_x),np.min(self.scale_y),np.max(self.scale_y)])        
            self.ax3.set_xlim(np.min(self.data),np.max(self.data)) 
            self.ax2.set_ylim(np.min(self.data),np.max(self.data))
            
    
                    
            #Create Curser @ minimum-minimum position of the axes
            self.lx = self.ax1.axhline(color='k')  # the horiz line
            self.ly = self.ax1.axvline(color='k')  # the vert line        
            self.lx.set_ydata(np.min(self.scale_y))
            self.ly.set_xdata(np.min(self.scale_x))
    
            #Creates sliced plots @ initial values of the curser
            # the change of scale needs to be considered therefore
            # the program checks for the minimum difference between curser pos and self.scale_... entries 
            # and uses the position of the entry to slice the data array
            self.slice_y,=self.ax3.plot(np.flipud(self.data[:,np.argmin(np.abs(self.scale_x-self.ly.get_xdata()))]),self.scale_y)
            self.slice_x,=self.ax2.plot(self.scale_x,self.data[np.shape(self.scale_y)-np.argmin(np.abs(self.scale_y-self.lx.get_ydata()))-1,:][0])
            # garanties fixed distances beetween the plots
            plt.tight_layout()
    
    
        def sliced_vertical(self,ax):
            #gets the sliced vertical sliced data
            self.slice_y.set_xdata(np.flipud(self.data[:,np.argmin(np.abs(self.scale_x-self.ly.get_xdata()))]))
        
        def sliced_horizontal(self,ax):
            #gets the horizontal sliced data
            self.slice_x.set_ydata(self.data[np.shape(self.scale_y)-np.argmin(np.abs(self.scale_y-self.lx.get_ydata()))-1,:])  
    
            
        def cursermovement(self,event):
            """
            tracks the curser movement and if a left click appeard near the curser
            the curser will folow the motion
            """
            if not event.inaxes:
                return
            if self.motion:   
                x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
                # update the line positions
                self.lx.set_ydata(y)
                self.ly.set_xdata(x)
                #update the text
                self.txt.set_text('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))
                #update the sliced data            
                self.sliced_vertical(self.ax2)
                self.sliced_horizontal(self.ax3)
                #replot everything
                plt.draw()        
            
            
        def mouse_move(self, event):
            self.cursermovement(event)
                
        def mouse_press(self,event):
            #check range for moving the cursers here in case of zoom in or out
            self.range_x=np.abs(self.ax1.get_xlim()[0]-self.ax1.get_xlim()[1])/20
            self.range_y=np.abs(self.ax1.get_ylim()[0]-self.ax1.get_ylim()[1])/20           
            # check if click occurred near cursor
            if (self.ly.get_xdata()+self.range_x>event.xdata>self.ly.get_xdata()-self.range_x) or (self.lx.get_ydata()+self.range_y>event.ydata>self.lx.get_ydata()-self.range_y):
                self.motion=True
            #curser jumps without motion to the mouse    
            self.cursermovement(event)
            
        def mouse_release(self,event):
            #checks if rigth mouse button was released
            self.motion=False
            
            
            
    """
    program starts here
    """        
    # define the plot range in x and y axes and change array size       
    t = np.arange(0.0, 40.0, 0.01)
    t2 = np.arange(0.0, 20.0, 0.01)
    #create a 2d grid to create the intensity map
    t_x,t_y=np.meshgrid(t,t2)
    #create the intensity map
    s = 10*np.sin(0.1*np.pi*(t_x))*np.sin(0.5*np.pi*t_y)+t_x+t_y
    #create the Gui class
    cursor = Cursor(s,t,t2)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib provides a widget called [`Cursor`](https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Cursor). You can use this already for the lines in the heatmap plot. This can use blitting in order not to redraw the canvas all the time,

```
matplotlib.widgets.Cursor(ax1,useblit=True)
```

To update the plots next to it, you may use the same blitting technique, but need to implement it manually. This way only the lines that change while moving the mouse will be updated and hence the whole interactive experience is much smoother.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets
import numpy as np

# define the plot range in x and y axes and change array size       
t = np.arange(0.0, 40.0, 0.01)
t2 = np.arange(0.0, 20.0, 0.01)
#create a 2d grid to create the intensity map
t_x,t_y=np.meshgrid(t,t2)
#create the intensity map
s = 10*np.sin(0.1*np.pi*(t_x))*np.sin(0.5*np.pi*t_y)+t_x+t_y
#create the Gui class


fig=plt.figure(dpi=150)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(223,sharex=ax1)
ax3=fig.add_subplot(222,sharey=ax1)
ax1.margins(0)
ax2.margins(0)
ax3.margins(0)
ax2.set_ylim(s.min(), s.max())
ax3.set_xlim(s.min(), s.max())

ax1.imshow(s,aspect='auto')
l2, = ax2.plot(np.arange(0,s.shape[1]),np.ones(s.shape[1])*np.nan)
l3, = ax3.plot(np.ones(s.shape[0])*np.nan, np.arange(0,s.shape[0]))


class Cursor():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.cursor = matplotlib.widgets.Cursor(ax1,useblit=True,**kwargs)
        self.cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.cursor_move)
        self.cid2 = fig.canvas.mpl_connect("draw_event", self.clear)
        self.bg1 = None
        self.bg2 = None
        self.needclear = False

    def cursor_move(self,event):
        if event.inaxes == ax1:
            self.needclear = True
            x,y = int(event.xdata),int(event.ydata)
            slice_y = s[:,x]
            slice_x = s[y,:]
            l2.set_ydata(slice_x)
            l3.set_xdata(slice_y)
            fig.canvas.restore_region(self.bg1)
            fig.canvas.restore_region(self.bg2)
            l2.set_visible(True); l3.set_visible(True)
            ax2.draw_artist(l2)
            ax3.draw_artist(l3)
            fig.canvas.blit(ax2.bbox)
            fig.canvas.blit(ax3.bbox)
        else:
            if self.needclear:
                self.clear()
                self.needclear = False

    def clear(self, event=None):
        l2.set_visible(False); l3.set_visible(False)
        self.bg1 = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax2.bbox)
        self.bg2 = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax3.bbox)

c = Cursor(color="crimson")

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you only want to move the cursor on clicking, instead of moving the mouse, you can disconnect its events and connect a new `button_press_event`. The relevant part of the code would then be

```
# code as above

class Cursor():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.cursor = matplotlib.widgets.Cursor(ax1,useblit=True,**kwargs)
        self.cursor.disconnect_events()
        self.cursor.connect_event('draw_event', self.cursor.clear)
        self.cursor.connect_event('button_press_event', self.cursor.onmove)

        self.cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.cursor_move)
        self.cid2 = fig.canvas.mpl_connect("draw_event", self.clear)
        self.bg1 = None
        self.bg2 = None
        self.needclear = False

    # rest of code as above
```

Comment: fisrt thanks for the improvement, but is there a possibility to simply make the cursor only moving when clicking, like its handeld in my example?

Comment: looked the source code of the curser function looks like its not possible i will write my one then.  Nevertheless thanks for your help

Comment: What exactly is the desired outcome? If it is to only update the marginal plots on clicks, you can simply replace `"motion_notify_event"` by `"button_press_event"`.

Comment: What exactly is the desired outcome? If it is to only update the marginal plots on clicks, you can simply replace `"motion_notify_event"` by `"button_press_event"`. If you only want the cursor to move when clicked (not moved), see updated answer.

Comment: Found a different solution. posted it as an additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the curser to be shiftable over the 2d Intensity map and then leave him at certain points, so i can watch the slices and also their changes in a smooth process.

Here is my current solution for my problem. The curser is like before initalized in the bottom left corner and you need to click at that position to drag him to the desigered position, where you release the left mouse. I implemented now also the curser blitting on my own. It is done in a similar wy to the matplotlib cursers with horizontal and vertical lines.
I also added now that you can change the number of cursers.
In the xample below its 5 (all of them spawn in the botttom left corner)
If you have a better idea or implementation i would be glad to here it.
Still i owe you because it runs now smothley with arrrays up to 10 Million entries:)
My next step is to add oblige angels to the cursers

[Find a picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLnie.png)

here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Jan 07 20:08:00 2018

@author: Sinthoras
"""
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


class GUI_Cursor(object):
        """
        creates a Gui objekt that plots given 2d data with imshow and creates a curser
        wich can be moved by drag and drop. The horizontal and vertical line of the curser
        are giving the position of a sliced trough the 2d-data and are plottet separetly.
        Scale _x and scale_y represent the scale of the axes and therefore needs to be given too
        """
        def __init__(self,data,scale_x,scale_y,numCur=1):

            self.choice=0
            self.numCur=numCur
            self.motion = False
            self.needclear = False
            self.bg1 = None
            self.bg2 = None
            self.bg_main = None
            self.data=data
            self.scale_x=scale_x 
            self.scale_y=scale_y 
            self.create_fig()
            self.create_events()


        def create_events(self):
            """
            Handles user events
            """
            self.cid1=plt.connect('motion_notify_event', self.mouse_move)
            self.cid2=plt.connect('button_press_event', self.mouse_press)
            self.cid3=plt.connect('button_release_event', self.mouse_release)
            self.cid4=plt.connect("draw_event", self.clear)

        def create_fig(self):
            """
            Creates the GUI, initializes the cursers at minimum of the axes and plots the 2d-data
            """

            #Create figure and subplots
            self.fig=plt.figure(dpi=150)
            self.ax1=self.fig.add_subplot(221)
            self.ax2=self.fig.add_subplot(223,sharex=self.ax1)
            self.ax3=self.fig.add_subplot(222,sharey=self.ax1)
            #self.cursor = matplotlib.widgets.Cursor(self.ax1,useblit=True)

            # plot in ax1
            self.main=self.ax1.imshow(self.data,interpolation='none',aspect='auto',extent=[np.min(self.scale_x),np.max(self.scale_x),np.min(self.scale_y),np.max(self.scale_y)])

            #Creates the limits for the three plots
            self.ax1.axis([np.min(self.scale_x),np.max(self.scale_x),np.min(self.scale_y),np.max(self.scale_y)]) 
            self.ax2.set_ylim(np.min(self.data),np.max(self.data))
            self.ax3.set_xlim(np.min(self.data),np.max(self.data)) 

            #garanties fixed distances beetween the plots
            plt.tight_layout()      
            #creates the curser as an object
            #also goes true the plotteing and everthing else needed
            self.Cursers=np.array([])
            for i in range (self.numCur):            
                        self.Cursers=np.append(self.Cursers,curser(self,i))


            print 'here weeeee are'


        def cursermovement(self,event):
            """
            tracks the curser movement and if a left click appeard near the curser
            the curser will folow the motion
            """

            if event.inaxes:            
                if self.motion: 
                    self.needclear = True
                    x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata

                    #restore the regions in the individual subplots:                                  
                    self.fig.canvas.restore_region(self.bg_main)
                    self.fig.canvas.restore_region(self.bg1)
                    self.fig.canvas.restore_region(self.bg2) 

                    for cur in self.Cursers:
                      if(cur==self.choice):  
                          cur.update(x,y)
                      else:
                          cur.update(None,None)
                                #blit command for the subplots
                    self.fig.canvas.blit(self.ax1.bbox)
                    self.fig.canvas.blit(self.ax2.bbox)
                    self.fig.canvas.blit(self.ax3.bbox)      
                    #update the text
                    #self.txt.set_text('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))



        def clear(self, event=None):
            print 'here'

            for cur in self.Cursers:                
                cur.clear()

            self.bg_main=self.fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax1.bbox)
            self.bg1 = self.fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax2.bbox)
            self.bg2 = self.fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax3.bbox)


        def mouse_move(self, event):
            self.cursermovement(event)

        def mouse_press(self,event):
            #check range for moving the cursers here in case of zoom in or out
            self.range_x=np.abs(self.ax1.get_xlim()[0]-self.ax1.get_xlim()[1])/20
            self.range_y=np.abs(self.ax1.get_ylim()[0]-self.ax1.get_ylim()[1])/20  

            # check if click occured near curser

            min_x=np.abs(self.Cursers[0].lx.get_ydata()-event.ydata)
            min_y=np.abs(self.Cursers[0].ly.get_xdata()-event.xdata)  

            self.choice=self.Cursers[0]
            for cur in self.Cursers:

                if ((np.abs(cur.lx.get_ydata()-event.ydata)<min_x) or (np.abs(cur.ly.get_xdata()-event.xdata)<min_y)):

                    min_x=np.abs(cur.lx.get_ydata()-event.ydata)
                    min_y=np.abs(cur.ly.get_xdata()-event.xdata)
                    self.choice=cur

            if (min_x<+self.range_x) or (min_y<self.range_y):
                self.motion=True

            #curser jumps without motion to the mouse    
            self.cursermovement(event)

        def mouse_release(self,event):
            #checks if rigth mouse button was released
            self.motion=False

class curser(object):
    """
    Creates one vertical and one horizontal curser in the ax1 plot of the figure
    Input is simply the Gui class itself

    """

    def __init__(self,GUI,index):

            self.GUI=GUI
            self.index=index
            print GUI

            self.lx = GUI.ax1.axhline(color='k')  # the horiz line
            self.ly = GUI.ax1.axvline(color='k')  # the vert line 

            #sets the inital position of the curser needs to change maybe
            self.lx.set_ydata(np.min(self.GUI.scale_y))
            self.ly.set_xdata(np.min(self.GUI.scale_x))


            #Creates sliced plots @ initial values of the curser
            # the change of scale needs to be considered therefore
            # the programm checks for the minimum difference beetween curser pos and self.scale_... entries 
            # and uses the position of the entry to slice the data array
            self.slice_y,=self.GUI.ax3.plot(np.flipud(GUI.data[:,np.argmin(np.abs(self.GUI.scale_x-self.ly.get_xdata()))]),GUI.scale_y)
            self.slice_x,=self.GUI.ax2.plot(self.GUI.scale_x,GUI.data[np.shape(GUI.scale_y)-np.argmin(np.abs(self.GUI.scale_y-self.lx.get_ydata()))-1,:][0])


    def update(self,x,y):
            if(x!=None and y!=None):
                # update the line positions        
                self.lx.set_ydata(y)
                self.ly.set_xdata(x)
                #self.ly2.set_xdata(np.abs((np.min(self.GUI.scale_x)-np.max(self.GUI.scale_x)))/2)
                # updates the side plots for this curser
                self.slice_y.set_xdata(np.flipud(self.GUI.data[:,np.argmin(np.abs(self.GUI.scale_x-self.ly.get_xdata()))]))            
                self.slice_x.set_ydata(self.GUI.data[np.shape(self.GUI.scale_y)-np.argmin(np.abs(self.GUI.scale_y-self.lx.get_ydata()))-1,:])           
                #replot everything  


            #make sure the plots are visible
            self.lx.set_visible(True)
            self.ly.set_visible(True)
            self.slice_x.set_visible(True)
            self.slice_y.set_visible(True)

            #draw command for changed  element
            self.GUI.ax1.draw_artist(self.lx)
            self.GUI.ax1.draw_artist(self.ly)                    
            self.GUI.ax2.draw_artist(self.slice_x)
            self.GUI.ax3.draw_artist(self.slice_y)



    def clear(self):
                self.slice_x.set_visible(False)
                self.slice_y.set_visible(False)
                self.lx.set_visible(False)
                self.ly.set_visible(False)  


"""
programm starts here
"""        

    # define the plot range in x and y axes and change array size       
t = np.arange(0.0, 40.0, 0.015)
t2 = np.arange(0.0, 20.0, 0.01)
    #create a 2d grid to create the intensity map
t_x,t_y=np.meshgrid(t,t2)

    #create the intensity map
s = 10*np.sin(0.1*np.pi*(t_x))*np.sin(0.5*np.pi*t_y)+t_x+t_y

    #create the Gui class
cursor = GUI_Cursor(s,t,t2,5)
plt.show()
```

Greetings Sinthoras